# ¿Por que existe tanta diferencia en tiempo de ejecucion en estos 2 codigos de Mergesort?

Tags: java, algoritmos, ordenamiento

Actualmente tengo estas 2 maneras de hacerlo. La primera requiere mucho mayor tiempo de compilacion, no cumpliendo n*logn. La segunda si. No acabo de entender bien por que, lo achaco a las operaciones del arraylist.

La primera es esta

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Mergesort {    

    public static ArrayList mergesort (ArrayList <Comparable> a) {
        ArrayList <Comparable> arrayOne = new ArrayList <>(a.size());
        ArrayList <Comparable> arrayTwo= new ArrayList <>(a.size());
        if (a.size()==1) 
            return a;   
        for (int i=0 ; i<a.size()/2; i++)
            arrayOne.add(a.get(i));
        for (int i=a.size()/2 ; i<a.size() ; i++)
            arrayTwo.add(a.get(i));
        arrayOne = mergesort (arrayOne);            
        arrayTwo = mergesort (arrayTwo);            
        return merge (arrayOne, arrayTwo);  
    }

    public static boolean bigger (Comparable a, Comparable b) { // ¿a>b?    
        return a.compareTo(b)==1;
    }

    public static ArrayList merge (ArrayList <Comparable> a, ArrayList <Comparable>b){
        ArrayList <Comparable> c = new ArrayList <>(a.size());
        while (a.size()>0 && b.size()>0) {  //while (a and b have elements)
            if (bigger (a.get(0),b.get(0))) {   //a.get(0)>b.get(0)
                c.add(b.get(0));            //add b[0] to the end of c
                b.remove(b.get(0));}        //remove b[0] from b
            else {
                c.add(a.get(0));            //add a[0] to the end of c
                a.remove(a.get(0));}}       //remove a[0] from a


        while (a.size()>0) {
            c.add(a.get(0));            //add a[0] to the end of c
            a.remove(a.get(0));}        //remove a[0] from a

        while (b.size()>0) {
            c.add(b.get(0));            //add b[0] to the end of c
            b.remove(b.get(0));}        //remove b[0] from b
        return c;
    }
}
```

La segunda es esta

```
public class Mergesort {    

    private int[] array;
    private int[] tempMergArr;
    private int length;



    public void sort(int inputArr[]) {
        this.array = inputArr;
        this.length = inputArr.length;
        this.tempMergArr = new int[length];
        doMergeSort(0, length - 1);}

    private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {         
        if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
            int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;
            doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);
            doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);
            mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);}}

    private void mergeParts(int lowerIndex, int middle, int higherIndex) { 
        for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++)
            tempMergArr[i] = array[i];
        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = lowerIndex;
        while (i <= middle && j <= higherIndex) {
            if (tempMergArr[i] <= tempMergArr[j]) {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
                i++;}
            else {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[j];
                j++;}
            k++;}
        while (i <= middle) {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El código es un poco *denso* pero puede ser porque cuando haces un `remove`, a menos que sea el último elemento, obligas a ArrayList a mover todos los elementos con un índice mayor a ser movidos una posición. ArrayList no es la mejor implementación de List para la inserción/eliminación de elementos en medio de la lista

Comment: Eso pense, de ahi que lo implementase tambien con LinkedList y fuese aun peor, entiendo que por tener este el get, que tambien aparece mucho, como O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentarte ayudar en lo poco que se. Tengo este codigo de MSort en C pero tranquilamente se puede hacer en Java.

```
 void mezcla(Tlista l,int ini, int m, int fin)
{
    int aux[20]; int i,j,k,t;
    k=0;
    i=ini;
    j=m+1;
    while (i<=m && j<=fin){
        k++;
        if (l[i]<l[j]){
            aux[k]=l[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            aux[k]=l[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(t=i;t<=m;t++){
        k++;
        aux[k]=l[t];
    }
    for(t=j;t<=fin;t++){
        k++;
        aux[k]=l[t];
    }
    for(t=1;t<=k;t++)
        l[ini+t-1]=aux[t];
}


void m_sort(Tlista l, int ini, int fin)
{
    int m;
    m=(ini+fin)/2;
    if (ini<fin){
        m_sort(l,ini,m);
        m_sort(l,m+1,fin);
        mezcla(l,ini,m,fin);
    }
}
```

Investigando un poco pude encontrar que el mejor tipo de lista para agregar y eliminar elementos es LinkedList, espero te sirva de algo!

Answer (score 0):

Esta mañana estuve implementando el Mergesort desde la perspectiva "bottom-up", utilizando arraylist y estoy teniendo unos tiempos de ejecucion en la linea de lo esperable. Me quedo mas intrigado aun por que le pasara al codigo de mi pregunta inicial.

```
package bottomUp.secondAttempt;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MergeSort {

    private int sz;
    private Comparable [] array;

    public MergeSort (Comparable [] array) {
        this.array = array;}

    public void sort () {
        sz = 1;     
        while (sz<array.length) {
            int i=0;
            while (i<array.length-sz+1) {
                ArrayList <Comparable> a1 = new ArrayList<>(sz);
                ArrayList <Comparable> a2Arr = new ArrayList <>(sz);                
                Comparable [] temp = new Comparable [2*sz];

                int l=i;
                int m=i+sz;
                for (int j=0; j<sz ; j++) {
                    a1.add(array [l]);  
                    l++;}
                int j=0;
                while (j<sz && m<array.length) {
                    a2Arr.add(array [m]);
                    m++;
                    j++;}
                Comparable [] a2 = new Comparable [a2Arr.size()];
                a2Arr.toArray(a2);
                temp = merge (a1, a2Arr);               
                System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, i, temp.length);                   
                i =i+2*sz;}         
            sz = sz * 2;}}

    public static Comparable [] merge (ArrayList <Comparable> a, ArrayList <Comparable> b){

        Comparable [] c = new Comparable [a.size()+b.size()];
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        while (i<a.size() && j<b.size()) {  
            if (bigger(a.get(i), b.get(j))){        // a>b
                c[k]=b.get(j);
                j++;
                k++;}
            else {                          // a<b
                c[k] = a.get(i);
                i++;
                k++;}}  
            //At this point either array a or array b are empty. We'll read only from the one that still has elements           
        while (i<a.size()) {
            c[k] = a.get(i);
            i++;
            k++;}       
        while (j<b.size()) {
            c[k]=b.get(j);
            j++;
            k++;}       
        return c;}  

    public static boolean bigger (Comparable a, Comparable b) { // ¿a>b?
        return a.compareTo(b)>0;}

    public Comparable[] getArray() {
        return array;}

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        int size = 4000000;     //1.000.000
        Comparable [] randNumbUnsorted= new Comparable [size];
        for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
            randNumbUnsorted [i]=((int)(Math.random()*size*10));
        System.out.println("start");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort ms2 = new MergeSort (randNumbUnsorted);
        ms2.sort();     
        System.out.println("end. Time elapsed "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
```

Comment: si esto no es una respuesta no debe ir en esta parte, no olvides que esto no es un foro, sino un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, entonces editalo y argumenta el por que esto es una respuesta o elimínalo y agrégalo en tu pregunta